# What honorific does Panda use when speaking to Yaga Masamichi?

Tags: japanese-language, jujutsu-kaisen

In *Jujutsu Kaisen*'s episode 16 "Kyoto Sister School Exchange Event—Group Battle 2—" (Transcription: Kyōto Shimai-kō Kōryū-kai—Dantai-sen ②—; Japanese: 京都姉 妹校交流会—団体戦②—), during a flashback scene explaining Panda's origin, we have the following conversation between Yaga Masamichi, principal of the Tokyo school and Panda's creator, and Panda as a toddler or "preschooler":

> **Yaga:** Panda. Actually, you have an older brother and sister.
> **Panda:** I don't.
> **Yaga:** No, you do. They are in your body. *<mutters to self>* What's with the honorific?

What exactly is the honorific that Panda uses here? I am somewhat aware that there is a hierarchy of formal speech in the Japanese language, but I'm not able to precisely identify what honorific is being used in the Japanese dub. Is it perhaps the *—⁠masen* ending used by Panda? Furthermore, what is unusual about Panda using that kind of speech with Yaga, prompting him to comment upon it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He says "いませんけど", so you are correct that it's the -*masen* ending since there isn't really anything else in that response anyway.

The reason this is odd is because of what Yaga says that Panda is responding to:

> お前にはお兄ちゃんとお姉ちゃんがいるんだ。

(You have an older brother and an older sister.)

If Yaga were speaking in the formal register he would've said:

> あなたにはお兄ちゃんとお姉ちゃんがいます。

Or something similar to that. Basically, お前 is pretty informal and いる（んだ） is the short / casual form of "to exist", so for Panda to respond in formally is strange.

The translated subtitle when I went to look for this scene had Yaga's response as "And why the polite tone?".

So I believe this is just a translation error. There was no honorific but Panda responded in the polite register which prompted Yaga's confusion.