# What exactly does Sukuna say when Itadori breaks into Mahito's Domain Expansion?

Tags: japanese-language, jujutsu-kaisen

In *Jujutsu Kaisen*'s episode 13 "Tomorrow" (Transcription: "Mata Ashita"; Japanese: また明日), when Nanami Kento is trapped in Mahito's Domain Expansion "Self-Embodiment of Perfection" (*Jihei Endonka*), Itadori Yuji manages to break into it from the outside. Due to the nature of the domain, this brings Itadori—and hence also Ryomen Sukuna—into Mahito's contact. For the insolence of touching him, Sukuna proceeds to deliver a near fatal blow to Mahito while thinking the following:

> It's either you die… or I die. It doesn't matter. Except for that guy *<scene showing Fushiguro Megumi>*, I couldn't care less.

This doesn't really make sense to me. Sukuna has no reason to be callous about his own existence in the situation. On the contrary, the entire scene shows, as far as Sukuna is concerned, any life can be taken or spared just based on his whims.

From my limited knowledge of Japanese, I would expect the word "*ore*" or some variant to appear in a phrase such as "or I die", but I hear the word "*omaye*" in both parts of the sentence, so Sukuna is probably saying "It's either you die… or you die," I guess?

Additionally, visually the part "It's either you die…" is said while the scene shows Nanami, and the part "or I die" is said while the scene shows Mahito writhing in agony.  So, I think it would make a lot more sense visually, too, if the subtitles were to instead read "It's either you die… or you die."

Could someone please clarify what the precise Japanese lines are in this scene, and whether the subtitles quoted in the beginning are indeed incorrect? The scene occurs at around 13:00.

---

<sup>In case it matters, I am watching the series on Netflix, and the subtitles there are slightly off in at least one other instance: see [What honorific does Panda use when speaking to Yaga Masamichi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/65733/what-honorific-does-panda-use-when-speaking-to-yaga-masamichi).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just watched the scene. I think your understanding is correct.

He says お前が死のうと、お前が死のうと、どうでもいい (Omae ga sinouto, Omae ga sinouto, doudemo ii), which literally translates to *you die, or you die, it does not matter (to me)*.

As you have correctly guessed the two *you*'s refer to different persons, the one in gray suit and the one bleeding. So a more idiomatic translation would be *I don't care which of you guys die*.